# Trying to use FPDI with TCPDF using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to use FPDI with TCPDF in symfony2.

I could use TCPDF alone without any problems. But when I try to use FPDI, I'm getting errors.

In my composer.json i put the following:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/"
         },
         "classmap": ["vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php","vendor/fpdi/fpdi.php"]    
    },
```

Then in the controller I can instantiate a TCPDF class

```
$tcpdf = new \TCPDF();
```

But when I try to instantiate a FPDI instance

```
$fpdi = new \FPDI();
```

Symfony throws me the following error when I try to access the route.

*FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\vendor\fpdi\fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php line 169
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\Consulta\vendor\fpdi\fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php line 169*

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

I'm adding the content of fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php

```
<?php
//
//  FPDI - Version 1.4.4
//
//    Copyright 2004-2013 Setasign - Jan Slabon
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//  limitations under the License.
//



/**
 * This class is used as a bridge between TCPDF and FPDI
 * and will create the possibility to use both FPDF and TCPDF
 * via one FPDI version.
 * 
 * We'll simply remap TCPDF to FPDF again.
 * 
 * It'll be loaded and extended by FPDF_TPL.
 */
class FPDF extends TCPDF {

    function _putstream($s) {
        $this->_out($this->_getstream($s));
    }

    function _getxobjectdict() {
        $out = parent::_getxobjectdict();
        if (count($this->tpls)) {
            foreach($this->tpls as $tplidx => $tpl) {
                $out .= sprintf('%s%d %d 0 R', $this->tplprefix, $tplidx, $tpl['n']);
            }
        }

        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Encryption of imported data by FPDI
     *
     * @param array $value
     */
    function pdf_write_value(&$value) {
        switch ($value[0]) {
            case PDF_TYPE_STRING:
                if ($this->encrypted) {
                    $value[1] = $this->_unescape($value[1]);
                    $value[1] = $this->_encrypt_data($this->_current_obj_id, $value[1]);
                    $value[1] = TCPDF_STATIC::_escape($value[1]);
                } 
                break;

            case PDF_TYPE_STREAM:
                if ($this->encrypted) {
                    $value[2][1] = $this->_encrypt_data($this->_current_obj_id, $value[2][1]);
                    $value[1][1]['/Length'] = array(
                        PDF_TYPE_NUMERIC,
                        strlen($value[2][1])
                    );
                }
                break;

            case PDF_TYPE_HEX:
                if ($this->encrypted) {
                    $value[1] = $this->hex2str($value[1]);
                    $value[1] = $this->_encrypt_data($this->_current_obj_id, $value[1]);

                    // remake hexstring of encrypted string
                    $value[1] = $this->str2hex($value[1]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unescapes a PDF string
     *
     * @param string $s
     * @return string
     */
    function _unescape($s) {
        $out = '';
        for ($count = 0, $n = strlen($s); $count < $n; $count++) {
            if ($s[$count] != '\\' || $count == $n-1) {
                $out .= $s[$count];
            } else {
                switch ($s[++$count]) {
                    case ')':
                    case '(':
                    case '\\':
                        $out .= $s[$count];
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        $out .= chr(0x0C);
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        $out .= chr(0x08);
                        break;
                    case 't':
                        $out .= chr(0x09);
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        $out .= chr(0x0D);
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        $out .= chr(0x0A);
                        break;
                    case "\r":
                        if ($count != $n-1 && $s[$count+1] == "\n")
                            $count++;
                        break;
                    case "\n":
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Octal-Values
                        if (ord($s[$count]) >= ord('0') &&
                            ord($s[$count]) <= ord('9')) {
                            $oct = ''. $s[$count];

                            if (ord($s[$count+1]) >= ord('0') &&
                                ord($s[$count+1]) <= ord('9')) {
                                $oct .= $s[++$count];

                                if (ord($s[$count+1]) >= ord('0') &&
                                    ord($s[$count+1]) <= ord('9')) {
                                    $oct .= $s[++$count];    
                                }                            
                            }

                            $out .= chr(octdec($oct));
                        } else {
                            $out .= $s[$count];
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    /**
     * Hexadecimal to string
     *
     * @param string $hex
     * @return string
     */
    function hex2str($hex) {
        return pack('H*', str_replace(array("\r", "\n", ' '), '', $hex));
    }

    /**
     * String to hexadecimal
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    function str2hex($str) {
        return current(unpack('H*', $str));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another error behind that, ignore the fact that `ContextErrorException` doesn't seem to exist. Find the problem that is causing it to try to throw that exception.  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Hi,
Symfony2 shows me no Stack Trace about this.
I've written all the error information shown in Symfony2.

In my controller code, the only thing I did is

  `  function probandoFPDIAction() {
        $pdf = new \FPDI;
    }`

Comment: Can you paste bin `fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php` please

Comment: Yes, of course.
I'm new on SO, so i don't know what you mean by "paste bin".

I've added the content of the file to the question...

Comment: Line 169 is the end of the class. Looks like a namespace problem.  Try adding a backslash to the `TCPDF` in `class FPDF extends TCPDF`.  I know it is modifying vendor code, but may point us to the problem.

Comment: Hi,
I had already tried that and it didn't work. 
I paste the original content of the file.
If I add the backslash the error shown is exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the packagist reference to composer.json the normal way:

https://packagist.org/packages/setasign/fpdi

`"setasign/fpdi": "1.4.2"`

That appears to be an alias of `https://github.com/mark9000/FPDI.git`

That should autoload it correctly.

Comment: If you are using the command line do: `php composer.phar require setasign/fpdi 1.4.2`, but remove that classmap property

Comment: Hi,
It worked !!

I removed both TCPDF and FPDI from the classmap of the composer.json. 

Then I add both:
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "dev-master",
        "setasign/fpdi": "1.4.2",

To the "requiere" part of the composer.json and it works :)

Thanks !